# Build docker compose for staging environment

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

This is my docker compose

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend

services:

  #=======================================================================
  #================================STAGING-TEST.DATABASE===========================
  #=======================================================================

  #==================MSSQL===================
  database-staging-test:
    build:
      context: .init/mssql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.mssql-database
    hostname: database-staging-test

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 1
        window: 120s

    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}
      MSSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      MSSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_VOLUME}:/var/opt/mssql/data

    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PORT}:1433

    networks:
      - backend






  #=======================================================================
  #==============================STAGING-TEST.CLIENT==============================
  #=======================================================================

  #==================CLIENT==================
  client:
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.client
    hostname: client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "3"
          memory: 2024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 1048M

    networks:
      - backend

    environment:
      VITE_APP_KEYCLOAK_URL: ${KEYCLOAK_URL}
      VITE_APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM: ${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
      VITE_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      VITE_APP_API_GATEWAY_URL: ${GATEWAY_HOST}
      VITE_APP_API_GATEWAY_PORT: ${GATEWAY_PORT}
      VITE_APP_CLIENT_URL: ${CLIENT_URL}

  #=======================================================================
  #==============================STAGING-TEST.TOOLS===============================
  #=======================================================================

  #==================ZIPKIN==================
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: staging-test.tools.zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 512M


  #================SONARQUBE=================
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:9.9.1-community
    container_name: staging.tools.sonarqube
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP}:${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PORT};databaseName=sonar;encrypt=false;
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${SONARQUBE_PORT}:9000
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 2048M


  #==============REDIS-COMMANDER==============
  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    container_name: staging-test.tools.redis-commander

    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 256M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.25"
          memory: 128M

  #=======================================================================
  #===============================STAGING-TEST.INFRA==============================
  #=======================================================================

  #==================REDIS===================
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: staging-test.infra.cache-redis
    command: redis-server #--requirepass sOmE_sEcUrE_pAsS

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 512M

    ports:
      - ${CACHE_PORT}:6379

    volumes:
      - ${CACHE_DATA_VOLUME}:/var/lib/redis
      - ${CACHE_CONFIG_VOLUME}:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

    networks:
      - backend

    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master

  #==================KEYCLOAK================
  keycloak-service:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    container_name: staging-test.infra.auth-keycloak
    hostname: keycloak-service
    environment:
      KC_DB: mssql
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP};databaseName=keycloak;trustServerCertificate=false;encrypt=false
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}

      KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED: false

      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: true
      KC_HTTPS_PORT: 8180

      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_USER} #username for master realm
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD} #password for master realm
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO

      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/certs/keycloakcert.pem
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/certs/keycloakkey.pem
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: https://${KEYCLOAK_URL}
      KC_HOSTNAME_URL: https://${KEYCLOAK_URL}

    ports:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_PORT}:8180

    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
      - database-staging-test

    command:
      - start
      #--hostname=flowcontrol.limax.nl #-> set hostname so token issuer is always correct, will only work when DNS setup.

    volumes:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/json/export:/opt/keycloak/data #map the export folder of the linux machine to my windows folder
      - ./keycloak/themes:/opt/keycloak/themes #map the custom themes folder to the correct location on the linux machine
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers #map the custom providers folder to the correct location on the linux machine
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/certs:/opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/certs #map the certs folder to the correct location on the linux machine

    networks:
      - backend

    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 2048M

  #==================EUREKA==================
  eureka-service:
    container_name: staging-test.infra.eureka-discovery-service
    hostname: eureka-service
    image: ${EUREKA_IMAGE}:${EUREKA_IMAGE_TAG}

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 512M

    ports:
      - ${EUREKA_PORT}:8761

    networks:
      - backend

    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:${EUREKA_PORT}/eureka




  #=======================================================================
  #===========================STAGING-TEST.SERVICES===============================
  #=======================================================================

  #==================GATEWAY=================
  gateway-service:
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.gateway-service
    hostname: gateway-service
    image: ${GATEWAY_IMAGE}:${GATEWAY_IMAGE_TAG}

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 2048M
        reservations:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1024M

    ports:
      - ${GATEWAY_PORT}:8762

    depends_on:
      - eureka-service

    networks:
      - backend

    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:${EUREKA_PORT}/eureka
      spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.'[/**]'.allowedOrigins: https://${CLIENT_URL}
      ssl.key-store.classpath: springStore.p12
      ssl.key-store-password: changeit
      ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
      ssl.key-alias: spring

  #==================FARMER====================
  farmer-service:
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.farmer-service
    hostname: farmer-service
    image: ${FARMER_IMAGE}:${FARMER_IMAGE_TAG}

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 3072M

    expose:
      - ${FARMER_PORT}

    networks:
      - backend

    depends_on:
      - keycloak-service

    volumes:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/certs:/certs #map the certs folder to the linux machine

    command:
      - keytool -importcert -alias keycloak -file /certs/keycloakcert.pem -keystore /usr/local/openjdk-18/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt # command to import cert into java keystore

    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: ${FARMER_PORT}
      MODULES_ARTICLE-ENDPOINT: https://article-service:${ARTICLE_PORT}
      MODULES_TRANSPORT-ENDPOINT: https://transport-service:${TRANSPORT_PORT}

      SPRING_DATASOURCE_FARMER_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP}:${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PORT};databaseName=farmer;trustServerCertificate=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_FARMER_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_FARMER_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE-SERVER_JWT_ISSUER-URI: https://${KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:${EUREKA_PORT}/eureka
      SPRINGDOC_SWAGGER_UI_OAUTH_CLIENT-ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASE-URL: http://zipkin:9411
      KAFKA.BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS: kafka:9092
      LOGGING.LEVEL.ROOT: INFO

  #==================ARTICLE==================
  article-service:
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.article-service
    hostname: article-service
    image: ${ARTICLE_IMAGE}:${ARTICLE_IMAGE_TAG}

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 3072M

    expose:
      - ${ARTICLE_PORT}

    networks:
      - backend

    depends_on:
      - keycloak-service

    volumes:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/certs:/certs #map the certs folder to the linux machine

    command:
      - keytool -importcert -alias keycloak -file /certs/keycloakcert.pem -keystore /usr/local/openjdk-18/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt # command to import cert into java keystore

    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: ${ARTICLE_PORT}

      #When connecting to a database in docker, do only use the IP / hostname of the container. Adding ports makes docker not understand anymore
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP};databaseName=article;trustServerCertificate=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE-SERVER_JWT_ISSUER-URI: https://${KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:${EUREKA_PORT}/eureka
      SPRINGDOC_SWAGGER_UI_OAUTH_CLIENT-ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASE-URL: http://zipkin:9411
      KAFKA.BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS: kafka:9092

  #==================TRANSPORT================
  transport-service:
    container_name: staging-test.flowcontrol.transport-service
    hostname: transport-service
    image: ${TRANSPORT_IMAGE}:${TRANSPORT_IMAGE_TAG}

    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 2
        window: 120s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 3072M

    expose:
      - ${TRANSPORT_PORT}

    networks:
      - backend

    depends_on:
      - keycloak-service

    volumes:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_VOLUME}/certs:/certs #map the certs folder to the linux machine

    command:
      - keytool -importcert -alias keycloak -file /certs/keycloakcert.pem -keystore /usr/local/openjdk-18/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt # command to import cert into java keystore

    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: ${TRANSPORT_PORT}
      MODULES_FARMER-ENDPOINT: https://farmer-service:${FARMER_PORT}
      MODULES_ARTICLE-ENDPOINT: https://article-service:${ARTICLE_PORT}

      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP};databaseName=transport;trustServerCertificate=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE-SERVER_JWT_ISSUER-URI: https://${KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:${EUREKA_PORT}/eureka
      SPRINGDOC_SWAGGER_UI_OAUTH_CLIENT-ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASE-URL: http://zipkin:9411
      KAFKA.BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS: kafka:9092
```

When I try to run it in the staging machine (the machine is with Ubuntu) I get this

```
flowcontrol@flow-test:~/Documenten/GitHub/RP-Flowcontrol$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-staging-testing.yml up -d
[+] Running 10/10
 ✘ eureka-service Error                                                                                                                                                          1.2s 
 ✘ farmer-service Error                                                                                                                                                          1.2s 
 ✘ redis Error                                                                                                                                                                   1.2s 
 ✘ keycloak-service Error                                                                                                                                                        1.2s 
 ✘ article-service Error                                                                                                                                                         1.2s 
 ✘ transport-service Error                                                                                                                                                       1.2s 
 ✘ gateway-service Error                                                                                                                                                         1.2s 
 ✘ sonarqube Error                                                                                                                                                               1.2s 
 ✘ zipkin Error                                                                                                                                                                  1.2s 
 ✘ redis-commander Error                                                                                                                                                         1.2s 
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gateway-module, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

The images should be created on initialization from the docker compose and it should not pull them online, also I am logged in and it still shows the error. When I run the compose on my pc it behaves differently. It starts and after some time it shows that I have connectivity issues related to my internet. What is going on? This is my env file:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=flowcontrol
# github secrets where possible
#Certificate
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=password

#Client
CLIENT_URL=localhost:8080
#CLIENT_URL=Something
#CLIENT_URL=Something

#Keycloak
KEYCLOAK_URL=keycloak-service:8180
#KEYCLOAK_URL=Something
#KEYCLOAK_URL=Something

KEYCLOAK_REALM=Flowcontrol
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=flow-control
KEYCLOAK_USER=Something
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=Something
KEYCLOAK_VERSION=23.0.4

KEYCLOAK_VOLUME=./keycloak/config

KEYCLOAK_PORT=8180

#Gateway
GATEWAY_HOST=localhost
#GATEWAY_HOST=Something
#GATEWAY_HOST=Something

GATEWAY_PORT=8762
EUREKA_PORT=8761

#Services
TRANSPORT_PORT=7072
ARTICLE_PORT=7078
FARMER_PORT=7071
PRODUCTION_PORT=7073

#Images
ARTICLE_IMAGE=article-module
ARTICLE_IMAGE_TAG=latest

FARMER_IMAGE=farmer-module
FARMER_IMAGE_TAG=latest

TRANSPORT_IMAGE=transport-module
TRANSPORT_IMAGE_TAG=latest

EUREKA_IMAGE=eureka-service
EUREKA_IMAGE_TAG=latest

GATEWAY_IMAGE=gateway-module
GATEWAY_IMAGE_TAG=latest

PRODUCTION_IMAGE=production-module
PRODUCTION_IMAGE_TAG=latest
#Database
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
# should be in github secrets
DATABASE_DEV_IP=database-dev
DATABASE_DEV_PORT=3386
DATABASE_DEV_INIT_VOLUME=./init
DATABASE_DEV_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/database/mssql/dev/
DATABASE_DEV_USERNAME=flowcontrolDev
DATABASE_DEV_PASSWORD=Something!

DATABASE_TEST_IP=database-test
DATABASE_TEST_PORT=3387
DATABASE_TEST_INIT_VOLUME=./init
DATABASE_TEST_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/database/mssql/test/
DATABASE_TEST_USERNAME=flowcontrolTest
DATABASE_TEST_PASSWORD=Something!

DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_IP=database-staging-test
DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PORT=3387
DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_INIT_VOLUME=./init
DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/database/mssql/prod-test/
DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_USERNAME=flowcontrolProd
DATABASE_STAGING_TEST_PASSWORD=Something!

DATABASE_PROD_IP=192.168.16.3
DATABASE_PROD_PORT=1437
DATABASE_PROD_USERNAME=flowcontrolProd
DATABASE_PROD_PASSWORD=Something!

#Cache
CACHE_PORT=6379
CACHE_DATA_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/redis/data/
CACHE_CONFIG_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/redis/config/redis.conf/

#Sonar
SONARQUBE_PORT=9000
SONARQUBE_DATA_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/sonarqube/data/
SONARQUBE_LOGS_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/sonarqube/logs/
SONARQUBE_EXTENSIONS_VOLUME=./docker-volumes/sonarqube/extensions/

#External
ECO_TOUCH_IP=192.168.1.150
ECO_TOUCH_PORT=3306
ECO_TOUCH_USERNAME=limax
ECO_TOUCH_PASSWORD=Something
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and reduce it to a [mcve]?  It seems like you're having an issue just pulling the image; do you have the same issue if you delete all of the containers except the troublesome one, and all of the settings besides `image:`, and ignore the environment file?  If you need to build the image locally, do you need a `build:` directive, or a separate `docker build -t gateway-module` command?